# Delete N lines, keep the next N and so on

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing

I want to delete the first 12 lines from a file, keep the next 12 lines and repeat this to the end of the file using a Linux command or shell-script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe it through `perl -nle 'print if ((($.-1)/12)%2)'`

Comment: missed ' at the end

Answer (score 3):

Using the facilities of GNU `awk`

```
awk -v RS='([^\\n]*\n){12}' '!(FNR % 2){printf "%s", RT}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` can choose ranges of lines, then delete them:

```
sed -i '1~24,+11d' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk variant:

```
awk '(NR-1)%24>11' file.txt > result.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

use `tail` "reversed"

```
tail -n +5
```

prints everything but the first five lines.

```
head -n 5
```

prints the first five lines.
So if you want to print lines 6 to 10:

```
cat yourfile | tail -n +5 | head -n 5
```